# GoLang: Return 2d slice for any type

Tags: function, go, 2d, slice

I know how to create a 2D slice like this.

```
var data []int
data = make([]int, w*h)
v := make([][]int, h)
for i := 0; i < h; i++ {
    v[i] = data[w*i : w*(i+1)]
}
```

Since this is very verbose and I'm going to create many of these, I decided to refactor it into a function.

```
func create2dSlice(w, h int) [][]int {
    var data []int
    data = make([]int, w*h)
    v := make([][]int, h)
    for i := 0; i < h; i++ {
        v[i] = data[w*i : w*(i+1)]
    }
    return v
}

func main() {
    a := create2dSlice(3, 2)
}
```

This works only for integers. It there any way in golang to do this for other types reusing the same code?

I come from C++ and I would expect to be able to do something like this.

```
create2dSlice<int>(w, h)
```

Comment: Go has no generics.

Comment: You can google `golang generics` and find an appropriate solution

Comment: How many different kinds of 2d slices are you needing? If you only need a specific number, it may be better to just have that number of specified functions as generators for those types of 2d slices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go doesn't have generics. For matrices, a similar problem, I have a `NewMatrix` function in a `matrix.go` file in my `snippet` folder. By design, I can simply copy it and do a global change of `[]int` to another type, for example, `[]float64`.

You could improve your function by giving `w` slices a valid capacity.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func NewMatrix(r, c int) [][]int {
    a := make([]int, c*r)
    m := make([][]int, r)
    lo, hi := 0, c
    for i := range m {
        m[i] = a[lo:hi:hi]
        lo, hi = hi, hi+c
    }
    return m
}

func create2dSlice(w, h int) [][]int {
    a := make([]int, w*h)
    s := make([][]int, h)
    lo, hi := 0, w
    for i := range s {
        s[i] = a[lo:hi:hi]
        lo, hi = hi, hi+w
    }
    return s
}

func main() {
    r, c := 2, 3
    m := NewMatrix(r, c)
    fmt.Println(m)
    w, h := c, r
    a := create2dSlice(w, h)
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0] [0 0 0]]
[[0 0 0] [0 0 0]]
```

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Slice expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions)
>
> Slice expressions construct a substring or slice from a string, array,
>   pointer to array, or slice. There are two variants: a simple form that
>   specifies a low and high bound, and a full form that also specifies a
>   bound on the capacity.
>
> Full slice expressions
>
> For an array, pointer to array, or slice a (but not a string), the
>   primary expression
>
> ```
> a[low : high : max]
> ```
>
> constructs a slice of the same type, and with the same length and
>   elements as the simple slice expression `a[low : high]`. Additionally,
>   it controls the resulting slice's capacity by setting it to `max - low`.

Comment: Why are you using `make` to create the `a` slice the length of  `c*r`. Won't it take less code to just make a slice the length of `c` inside the loop? Or is it bad to call `make` multiple times?

Comment: @Legarcon : The amount of code is not relevant. Performance (CPU time, bytes allocated, and number of allocations) is relevant. Calling `make` costs. Calling `make` multiple times costs more. Here's a benchmark of performance (PeterSO) versus less code (LeGarcon): `garcon_test.go`: https://play.golang.org/p/wY53-UNxKdT. There is also better [Locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference).

Answer (score 0):

Just have two methods that give you an int or a string 2d slice. Golang has no generics.

Comment: What a pity :-(

Answer (score 0):

To go in to this a little more. The reason Go wants you to type this out is because it makes code more clear. When balancing code clarity and code repetition, Go sides with clarity. Many languages take the 'no repeated code' side of this balance, but reduced clarity is a tradeoff. You do have a few options though if it's super important.
 1. Make an interface for all the possible return types. You could return [][]Number for example. 
 2. Make a struct that wraps the 2d array that has transfer methods, i.e. NumberArray.AsInts()
 3. Return the empty interface and use reflection.